# Swift - Table View

Tags: ios, swift

How to load data in table view end of all codes? For example, all functions will finish then the table view will load. Please let me know if you have any suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

at the end of all the functions

Answer (score 0):

"tableView" is camel case

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift**

```
tableview.reloadData()
```

**Objective C**

```
[tableview.reloadData]
```